# Find files with wrong date given filename

Tags: python, ruby, perl, bash, awk

I have a directory with files whose names are common with a suffix of increasing date.

An example is:

```
REUTERS.FH_lbm_dump.20120905
```

representing the 5th of September.

These files are supposed to be created in the first few minutes of the next day, e.g. the above file should've been created at 00:01 on the 6th of September.

However, due to some bug with how the filenames are generated, an application has been saving them incorrectly. So files created at 00:16 on the 5th of September have the suffix 20120905, i.e. the filename is 1 day too late.

Output from `ls -h` showing the wrong naming:

```
2012-09-05 00:16 FH_lbm_dump.20120905
```

So logic to detect this would look at the file name, extract the date, and if its equal to the file timestamp it would be positive.

How can we do this in Bash / Perl / Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will not solve your entire problem, but I'll give you a place to start. The rest is really up to you.

```
#!/bin/bash

# loop through all filenames in current dir
for filename in *; do

    # How to extract the date from the file name
    date_from_file=${filename:(-8)}

    # How to get the file's modification date in the same format
    date_modified=$(stat -c %y "$filename" | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sed 's/-//g')

    # test for inequality
    if [ $date_from_file -ne $date_modified ]; then

        ... # do your thing

    fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) for manipulating dates, and [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3astat) for convenient access to file statistics data

This program looks for all files in the current directory whose suffix is eight digits

It uses the `mtime` stat for each file to build a `Time::Piece` object, subtracts one day, and formats the date as `YYYYMMDD`

The result is compared with tha actual file suffix, and the file is reported as being incorrect if they differ

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;
use Time::Piece ();
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';

for my $file (glob '*') {

  next unless -f $file;
  my ($suffix) = $file =~ /([^.]+)\z/;
  next unless $suffix =~ /\A\d{8}\z/;

  my $dt = Time::Piece->new(stat($file)->mtime);
  $dt -= ONE_DAY;
  $dt = $dt->strftime('%Y%m%d');

  printf "File %s NOT CORRECT\n", $file unless $suffix eq $dt;
}
```